# XCode doesn't show all subclasses in drop-down when creating a new file

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I'm building an iOS application with Xcode 6 and I want to add a `UINavigationController` file into my project.

When I click 'New File' and select 'Cocoa Touch Class', it doesn't show all the subclasses it should in the specific project I'm working on. It used to be pretty long scroll-down, but now I see only eight options not containing `UINavigationController`.

What should I do to fix this problem?

[image: The options shown by the XCode]

Comment: Just type in _subclass of_ `UINavigationController`  and create it. It should work, Xcode often make this mistakes.

Comment: remove the string from "Class". Now hit tab to enter subclass of , start typing your Super class name, It will update the dropdown, just like the search in iPhone. :)

Comment: Thank you all.  I thought I might had done something wrong, but it was solved when I restarted Xcode a while later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the string from "Class". Now hit tab to enter subclass of , start typing your Super class name, It will update the dropdown, just like the search in iPhone. :)